# Scaling of App Engine Instances with Firebase

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was wondering how App Engine Instances are scaling in conjunction with the Firebase database.

Lets assume with have the following object structure at the database:

```
tasksForServer
- taskID
  - ...
  - ...
- taskID
  - ...
  - ...
```

Lets also assume that we have an Instance listening for every new child added to `tasksForServer`, so the Instance can process every task, which is coming in.

The amount of tasks coming in every second are north of 10.000 and have to be processed quickly. So even if there is not much to do for every task one Instance won't be able to handle the amount of task coming in sooner or later.

I've read that you can add more Instances in App Engine, but if I understand right, that's not working in this scenario, because of the way the Instance is listening for new tasks.

So, my first questions: Is the above correct? And if yes, what would be a solution?

I thought about ... splitting up the tasksForServer object like that ...

```
tasksForServer
- worker0
  - taskID
    - ...
  - taskID
    - ...
- worker1
  - taskID
    - ...
  - taskID
    - ...
```

... ,adding workers as needed and write the tasks randomly in the different "worker-queues".

Comment: As far as I have used App Engine, scaling happens automatically unless you explicitly define it in app.yaml to scale otherwise.

Comment: Have you used Firebase with App Engine as well? Data is retrieved with e.g. `ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {...});` So I think automatic scaling won't be possible because how would App Engine decide which Instance gets which new child.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add new instances, and app engine can do this for you if you [enable auto-scaling in your app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#scaling_elements). For your case, you may want to make the scaling depend on cpu utilization.

The problem with your approach, is all running instances will be processing the same tasks, which achieves nothing.

Luckily for you, [Firebase-Queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue) was built to solve this exact problem. With it, multiple queue workers can be initialized on multiple machines and Firebase-Queue will ensure that only one worker is processing a single queue task at a time. You can read more about firebase-queue in this [guide](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue/blob/master/docs/guide.md).

Comment: We've tried the Firebase-Queue before, but it was "kind of slow", but we may did something wrong on our side, so we'll give it another try soon ... Anyways, back to my approach. I try to make my self more clear, because I believe we have a misunderstanding here. Instance 1 would only listen on the worker1-node, Instance 2 only on the worker2-node and the clients would randomly write to just one worker*-node,  so tasks would be processed only by one Instance.